# How do i convert a weighted edglist in Python to a general edgelist?

Tags: python, pandas, edge-list

I have a weighted edgelist of data. It consists of source, destination and weight of the connection. Like this:

```
  source destination  weight
0      A           B       3
1      A           C       2
2      A           D       3
```

I want to have it in the general format that does not contain the weight value. The reason is that the application i am using does not consider the weight value in the dataset. Like this:

```
  source destination
0      A           B
1      A           B
2      A           B
3      A           C
4      A           C
5      A           D
6      A           D
7      A           D
```

I have tried using `reset_index()` and `unstack()` but the result i got was completely different from what i need.
Any suggestions ?

Comment: Specify which python package you are using.

Comment: also include any code you have tried so that we can repeat it

Comment: In what for is the data currently stored. Is that a `pandas` DataFrame, or something else?

Comment: i am using pandas dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`pd.Index.repeat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) and pass the `weight` column to have that number of repeats then call this under `df.loc[]`:

```
df.loc[df.index.repeat(df.weight),['source','destination']].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Alternate code with [`np.repeat()`](https://www.google.com/search?q=np+repeat&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN822IN823&oq=np+repeat&aqs=chrome..69i57j35i39l2j0l3.1645j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8):

```
final=(pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(df[['source','destination']].values,
  df.weight,axis=0),columns=['source','destination']))
```

---

```
  source destination
0      A           B
1      A           B
2      A           B
3      A           C
4      A           C
5      A           D
6      A           D
7      A           D
```

Answer (score 1):

Neatly done with a generator function. For simplicity's sake, let's say the data is a list of 3-tuples (source, destination, weight).

```
def weighted_to_general(edges):
    for source, destination, weight in edges:
        # Memory optimization: store the tuple only once
        source_destination = (source, destination)
        for n in range(weight):
            yield source_destination


data = [
    ('A', 'B', 3),
    ('A', 'C', 2),
    ('B', 'D', 3),
]

for source_destination in weighted_to_general(data):
    print(source_destination)
```

If you need a list instead, simply iterate the generator using `list()`:

```py
general_data = list(weighted_to_general(data))
```

Comment: The code above worked for me. How if i want to read from a csv file?

Comment: Use whatever method you'd like to read your CSV file into a list of 3-tuples like that. That's really beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'source': ['A', 'A', 'B'], 'destination': ['B', 'C', 'D'], 'weight': [3, 2, 3]})

result = list()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    for x in range(row.weight):
        result.append([row.source, row.destination])
print(pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['source', 'destination']))
```

Result:

```
  source destination
0      A           B
1      A           B
2      A           B
3      A           C
4      A           C
5      B           D
6      B           D
7      B           D
```

Comment: The code above worked for me. How if i want to read from a csv file?

Comment: You can read csv files with pandas: `df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv')`